# What are the options available for asp.net mvc paging with jQuery?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

As I know in current Asp.Net MVC3, there is a component available named WebGrid and in jQuery there is component available named jqgrid. Can anybody show a comparison of boh these components in terms of features and which is easy to setup and get going.

Also if there are any options for grid in jquery suggest them too. Few tutorials links etc. too may be helpful. I am complete beginner in Asp.Net MVC3.

Comment: I suggest you to change you post title, I don't see any relation between post's title and content.

Comment: S.Amini: Now is it proper? I have changed the content because I want suggestions from all before proceeding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check these out :

[Using jQuery Grid With ASP.NET MVC](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/14/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx)

[ASP.net MVC JQuery Json and Paging](http://byatool.com/ui/aspnet-mvc-jquery-json-and-paging-hows-that-for-a-soe-title/)

Answer (score 0):

Get the free telerik MVC open source controls . Is the easiest and most full featured one out there.

Comment: It is fake open source. We need to buy license for $999 if we use it for commercial purpose.

Comment: Also Telerik's controls take maximum time to load but MVC controls are built on top of jquery so it should be performant but my main concern is $999.

Comment: The controls stink and are heavy and unreliable too - they are awful.

Comment: Anthony you are speaking on things I believe you arent very clear on. Telerik uses jQuery and it's the best grid out there. The features are many and I've never had reliability issues - and no I don't work for them. Where did you see that you must pay the 999? Are you planning on distributing binaries ? If not then I dont believe it applies to you. Note they will attempt to load a version of jquery unless you tell it otherwise. @chris - name one better free grid? I'd be more than happy to check it out.

Comment: @Adam: jqGrid http://www.trirand.com/blog/ - I've had so many bad experiences with Telerik I won't ever use their products again.  Not only that, they delete anything critical to Telerik from their forum leaving an untrue representation of their products.